# Can't serve static files with feathersjs express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, feathersjs

I need to serve some image files from my app which are on a root folder called `uploads`.

I am setting the middleware on the same level as my folder. The code currently looks like this:

```
const express = require('@feathersjs/express')
const Path = require('path')

app.use('/uploads', express.static(Path.join(__dirname, `uploads`)))
```

If I try to do fetch a using `localhost:[MY_PORT_NUMBER]/uploads/myImage.jpg` I am currently getting a 404 and in the logs it is just getting the `NotFound: Resource not found` message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure the `app.js` file is a sibling of the `uploads` directory.

Comment: It is. They are in the same folder level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static(Path.join(__dirname, '/../uploads')));
```